# RDD with multiple cutoffs

Tags: microeconomics, regression, experimental-economics

I am trying to study the effects of a policy on educational attainment of individuals (years of schooling, primary/secondary school completion, literacy). Since the policy starts in a specific year I decided to use an RDD using birth year as running variable.

The problem is that my sample is made of 5 different countries in which the policy has been implemented in 5 different years. 
Am I able to pool the effect of the policy across countries?

Because if I build a unique running variable as being 0 for each cutoff year I get individuals born in e.g. 1994 having running variable both 0, -2, +3 depending on the country of origin.

How can I deal with this issue? Should I run a RD for each country alone?

Comment: You could consider generalized dif-in-dif also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This paper:https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2712957

Is exactly what you need.